# What is the best way to get a substring of a string array?

Tags: c#, string, split, substring

I have something like this:

```
string[] split = ListOfUsers.Split(new Char[] { ';', ',', ' ' });
```

Each string in "split" has an "@" sign at the beginning, and I want to get rid of it. What would be the ideal way to get the substring of this array, without getting into a for loop. Can I use Linq instead?

Thanks for looking :)

Comment: You can use String.Replace("@","") look up string.Replace() method on google.. tons of Examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an overload of [`String.Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx) that does exactly this: removes the specified characters from the beginning and end of a string:

```
string[] split = ListOfUsers.Split(new Char[] { ';', ',', ' ' });
string[] trimmed = split.Select(s => s.Trim('@')).ToArray();
```

If your strings contain multiple `@`s in the beginning or end with a `@` this will do more than you intended. In that case, you can also simply use [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx):

```
string[] split = ListOfUsers.Split(new Char[] { ';', ',', ' ' });
string[] trimmed = split.Select(s => s.Substring(1)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Select returns IEnumerable<string>, not string[]. would also trim the end of the string as well as the start.

Comment: @sweaver2112: Thanks for the catch, added an explicit conversion to array. The possible extra trimming is a problem for all solutions, and I already mention it.

Comment: No need to use LINQ, as you can use `Split` overloads that will split on `@` as well and remove empty entries.

Comment: @Oded: If there is a `@` inside the username that cannot be made to work. I 'm playing it safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
var split = ListOfUsers.Split(new Char[] { ';', ',', ' ' });
var cleaned = split.Select(s => s.Substring(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside trimming, as Jon suggested you can use regular expressions:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("@\\w*");
var userNames = regex.Matches(ListOfUsers).OfType<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be just add

```
ListOfUsers.Split(new Char[] { ';', ',', ' ', '@' })
```

so every sub-string will have the string you need.